Find the domain of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (e - (1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n)^{2x}$
I would like to find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(e - \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\right)^{2x}$.
In fact,  I knew that $\lim \left(e - \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\right) = 0$ and then this series is divergent when $x \leq 0$.
Do you have a solution to this problem when $x> 0$?
Thank you so much!

It might help to consider the function $$f(z)=e-e^{\ln(1+z)/z}.$$ Note that $f$ is analytic around $z=0$. Use this to get a suitable bound for your series.

With my hint you get $$e-(1+1/n)^n=f(1/n)=e-e^{1-1/(2n)+O(1/n^2)}=e/(2n)+O(1/n^2)$$ which should allow you to conclude.

May be you can consider some bounded inequalities like $e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n <\frac{3}{n}$.

Probably you mean $e$ instead of $e^n$. To get divergence, one also needs a similar lower bound.

@Severin Schraven oh yeah, I am sorry for making such a mistake

Yes, this is not yet an answer.

We can rewrite
$$ e - \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n
= e - e^{\ln(1+1/n)/(1/n)}. $$
For $y$ small we have using Taylor series
$$ e-e^{\ln(1+y)/y} = e -e^{1-\frac{1}{2}y+O(y^2)} = e - (e-e\frac{1}{2}y+O(y^2)) = \frac{e}{2}y+O(y^2). $$
With $y=1/n$ we get
$$ e - \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n
= e - e^{\ln(1+1/n)/(1/n)} = \frac{e}{2} \frac{1}{n}+O(1/n^2). $$
Thus, for $n$ large enough, we get
$$ \frac{1}{n} \leq e - \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \leq \frac{2}{n}. $$
By the comparison test, we get that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e - \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right)^{2x} $$
converges if and only if
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2x}}$$
converges. By the $p$-test, we get that the later converges if and only if $2x>1$. Thus, our series converges for $x>1/2$ and diverges otherwise (if one is pedantic, then one also needs this Show that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing to ensure that can raise our terms to a non-integer power).

In the very same spirit as @SeverinSchraven's answer but in a lighter formulation, using the symbol $\sim$ of asymptotic equivalence:
as $n\to\infty$
$$u_n:=n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)-1\sim-\frac1{2n}\to0$$
hence
$$v_n:=e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e\left(1-e^{u_n}\right)\sim-eu_n\sim\frac e{2n}.$$
Therefore,
$${v_n}^{2x}\sim\left(\frac e2\right)^{2x}\frac1{n^{2x}},$$
so that $\sum{v_n}^{2x}$ converges iff $2x>1$.

That's neat! I was a bit annoyed that my answer reads a bit heavily.

Thank you so much for nice solution.
